# Bootstrap navbar-collapse disappear after I click the toggle button with carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap navbar. and after this I have bootstrap carousel in the header of the site , then they work good on the lg and md screen ... but in the sm and xs screen when I click the button the navbar-collapse appear for a about 1 second then it disappear... I think that problem because of the carousel in the header but I don't know how to fix that.. I need some one to tell me the solution

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h3>Bondok <span>BE</span></h3></a>
                    </div><!-- navbar-header -->

                    <!-- links -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Resume &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-file-text fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-photo fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                 </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

and the style.scss is :

```
.navbar {
    @include border_r(0);
    margin: 0;
    background-color: $white_color;
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
    .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
        background-color: $main_color;
        span {
            background-color: $white_color;
        }
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        border-top: 3px solid $main_color;
        h3 {
            @include font_spec(24px, bold);
            margin-top: 0;
            span {
                color: $main_color;
                font-size: 28px;
            }
        }
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        z-index: 9999;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

}
```

Comment: your code working fine check `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKWqyG`

Comment: I know that the navbar is working fine but .. I have a carousel after it I don't know why the navs disappear in the sm and xs screen

Comment: Add your code with carousel. It seems nothing wrong with code. check this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKWqyG

Comment: I added the css and jquery code , check it now thanks a lot ,
http://codepen.io/Belal77/pen/dpzyRO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
.navbar-default{
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

no need z-index in `.wrapper .navbar .navbar-collapse`

Here is the working pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzqBok